# How to set and pass default values of kwargs from one function to another

Tags: python, python-decorators, keyword-argument

I have a few functions that call each other with a bunch of parameters.
Because my use case contains several parameters, I wanted to check that they are being passed correctly whenever I modify them (will wrap this in a verbose mode afterwards, but it's mainly for debug purposes now). Here's a toy example below:

```
from functools import wraps
import inspect

def print_kwargs(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # Print the function name
        print(f"Calling function {func.__name__}")
        # Print the values of the passed keyword arguments
        if kwargs:
            print("Keyword arguments:")
            for key, value in kwargs.items():
                print(f"  {key} = {value}")

        # Print the default values of keyword arguments defined in the function signature
        sig = inspect.signature(func)
        for param_name, param in sig.parameters.items():
            print(f"{param_name} : {param}")
            if param.default is not inspect.Parameter.empty:
                value = param.default
                if value is not None or (value is None and param_name in kwargs):
                    print(f"  {param_name} = {value}")

        # Call the function
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@print_kwargs
def fun1(a, **kwargs):
    n_remove = kwargs.get('n_remove', 0)
    b = fun2(a[n_remove:], **kwargs)
    return b

@print_kwargs
def fun2(x, **kwargs):
  return x
```

If I call

```
fun1([1,2,3], n_remove=1)
Calling function fun1
Keyword arguments:
  n_remove = 1
a : a
kwargs : **kwargs
Calling function fun2
x : x
kwargs : kwargs
[2, 3]
```

The keyword argument gets intercepted in the first call, but not the second one. `**kwargs` is printed "as is" instead of with the default value of 0. When I call the function with the default values I get nothing for keyword arguments (makes sense) and the same behavior for `**kwargs`.

```
fun1([1,2,3])
Calling function fun1
a : a
kwargs : **kwargs
Calling function fun2
x : x
kwargs : kwargs
[1, 2, 3]
```

I am not very familiar with the way **kwargs works and, although the functions seem to be working correctly and all the default values are properly set inside each function using the likes of `kwargs.get('n_remove', 0)`, I cannot figure out how to print the default values of my `kwargs`.

Comment: No "default" is ever assigned to `kwargs`. You use `0` as a default for the local variable `n_remove` when no such keyword argument is provided.

Comment: So, in order to "carry it over" I should set the default value if not given? How are these things handled?

Comment: Default values are tied to the function, not the arguments it might pass on. `func2` generally does not care whether or not its caller received an argument explicitly or as a default value.

Comment: So what is the recommended way to pass **kwargs between functions while allowing for default values to be used if the user does not write them down? I thought the `kwargs.get('var', 'default')` would be the way, but I'm definitely wrong. Do I need to both parse and set the kwargs on each `f(x)` ?

Comment: Don't use `kwargs` like this. Use `kwargs` when a function will receive some unknown set of keyword arguments only to pass on to another function. If you are expecting a particular argument (keyword or not), declare the parameter explicitly.

Comment: I have 3 to 5 functions calling each other (wrangling, fit, etc...). Each contains 3 to 10 parameters. Making it explicit creates 2 problems: 1) that parameter has to be propagated and 2) it's not super friendly for the intended use case. Reformating everything to a class would be an option but also somewhat unnecessary.

Comment: If you need to ensure that `n_remove` is passed as a keyword argument to `func2` whether or not `func1` received one as well, then `func1` will have to add it explicitly: `kwargs['n_remove'] = kwargs.get(n_remove, 0)`.